# Bind the first value from an ng-repeat without using ng-model or ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am on angular 1.2.26 and listing a set of values using ng-repeat and trying to bind the **first value** in the list to another html tag.

After quite a battle, i figured out 2 options to do it, as below.

**Option 1 - use ng-model within ng-repeat**

I bind the first value to another HTML tag using,

```
<tr ng-repeat="(id,word) in words | orderBy: '$id'">
    <td ng-model="words[id]">{{word.name}}</td>
    <td>{{word.score}}</td>
</tr>

<h3 align="center" ng-bind="words[0].name">
```

**Option 2 - probably a crude way is to use another ng-repeat with limitTo**

```
<tr ng-repeat="(id,word) in words | orderBy: '$id'">
    <td>{{word.name}}</td>
    <td>{{word.score}}</td>
</tr>

<h3 align="center" ng-repeat="(id,word) in words | orderBy: '$id' | limitTo: 1">
```

Would like to know if they which of these is better and if there exists an even better and simple way of doing it.

Specifically can i do it without applying the ng-model directive within ng-repeat ?

P.S : Excuse my primitive way of asking a question on being not too young & trying to learn to code :)

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve here. What's wrong with the `ngRepeat` from "Option 2" and the `h3` from "Option 1"? binding to `words[0].name` is perfectly fine.

Comment: looks like you are trying to order an object which you can't do in javascript. Provide some sample data and better explanation of higher level problem you are trying to solve

Comment: @seldary Nothing is wrong, it works as i mentioned in the question .i was just wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: You may have more luck on [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @charlietfl i am already ordering the list using the orderBy filter of angular, what i wanted to do is bind the value of the first item in the list elsewhere (which also works by way of both options in my question...). I just wanted to know if there is a better and more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: @JMK ok thanks, will try there...never knew about it..

Comment: no, you are over-complicating it. The second option is creating additional computation overhaed that is not needed

Comment: @charlietfl agree. tat's why i mentioned it as a rather crude option. So i guess 1st option is the most efficient & elegant of the 2 at least.

Comment: My suggestion is that you step by step moving the logic to the view (HTML) that's what angular trying to avoid, so you better be handle and data preparation in your Controller, there you can expose the first item using another scope property after you receive the data collection, then use it directly in the view. That's the cleanest way I guess

Comment: You can also save the result of the orderby an filters in an variable and take the first item of that array. `(id,word) in result = (words | orderBy: '$id')` and then use result[0]

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

> The second option is creating additional computation overhead that is not needed
>
> You can also save the result of the `orderBy` filter in a variable and take the first item of that array:

```
(id,word) in result = (words | orderBy: '$id')
```

> and then use `result[0]`